# Large Amount of Data Transferring via WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, service, data-transfer

I am using WCF in my project to transfer data from a server (which accesses the Database) and a client, which plots the data in the screen.

The amount of transferred data is rather big, so I would like to know which is the best way of doing it.

Right now, I am able to query small amounts of data, around 3600 objects (Timestamp and double value). However, when this number increases to around 86400 objects, an error in the service function call occurs.

My service and client are declared as follow:

Server:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="6553600"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="serviceName">
        <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" contract="interfaceName">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:5050/msservice"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Client:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IService" closeTimeout="00:02:00" openTimeout="00:02:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:02:00" transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10" maxConnections="10"  maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false"/>
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign"/>
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:5050/msservice" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IService" contract="IService" name="NetTcpBinding_IService">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost"/>
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Have you looked at streaming? [Large Data and Streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you on .net 4?  If not I believe you would need to supply a name for the service behavior and associate it with the service.

Edit: Otherwise, the default maxItemsInObjectGraph value of 65536 could be used.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
    <service name="YOURPROJECT.Web.YOURSERVICE"
            behaviorConfiguration="YOURPROJECT-Web-YOURSERVICE">
    </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="YOURPROJECT-Web-YOURSERVICE">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="6553600"/>
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: Please make note of the maxItemsInObjectGraph property, as this is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: I did and its set higher than what should cause the error. 6553600 > 86400.  The default is 65536.  It seems that the larger value is not recognized. Maybe due to behavior.

Comment: I am using .Net 4. Should I add the maxItemsInObjectGraph to 6553600 or to 2147483647?

Comment: For the sake of this test I would go with 2147483647.  Also, it might not hurt to explicitly associate the behavior to the service.  You shouldn't have to but may help troubleshooting.